# How will I do the following using Relative and absolute addressing?

Tags: linux, bash, kernel

I want to learn more about relative and absolute addressing.  I was wondering how can I do the following using relative and absolute addressing in Linux?

1. Using RELATIVE addressing, create a new folder called Demo1.
2. Using RELATIVE addressing, enter into the new folder Demo1.
3. Using ABSOLUTE addressing, enter into the new folder Demo1.

Please let me know!

Comment: Welcome, is this homework? Show what have you tried, where you got stuck, what reasearch did you do. Otherwise you won't get much help and the question is probably going to be closed.

Comment: I did research on what the difference is between relative and absolute addressing.  I looked at the meanings, etc.  I just want to know is there some specific command in relative addressing?  Or do I use the normal commands such as cd to go to a directory?

Comment: No relative and absolute work the same way when used in arguments. It's just "house no. 11 next street" vs "house no 11 on 5th avenue"

Comment: Well, I don't need help anymore.  The answer I was looking for was that Absolute uses more characters.  Relative addressing uses less characters.  For example, Aboslute would be like "cd /home/user1/SecDir"  Relative would be "cd SecDir".

Comment: Relative can use more characters (an extreme example `../../../../../../the-file` vs `/the-file` ). It is not about character count.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up terminology. I think you may be asking about **relative and absolute directory paths**.

An absolute path is the path (route) from the root of the file-system to where you are going.

A relative path is the path (route) from your current location.

Use the words in bold to look up more info. Using the correct keywords will make finding the information much easier.

Absolute and relative addressing usually refers to addressing modes of a processing unit (e.g. CPU).